# Magento 2: Url Not Displaying on Server

Tags: magento2, url

In my Local Below Url works fine & Displaying

```
  <a class="product-item-photo" href="<?php $this->getBaseUrl() . 'trade/buyingList'; ?>" title="<?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo __('View All'); ?>"><span><?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo __('View All'); ?></span></a>
```

On Server it's only displaying `<?php $this->getBaseUrl()`

I can access `abc.com/trade/buyingList` on my Server. Camelcase won't be issue i think. Cach

Comment: <?php $this->getBaseUrl().'trade/buyingList'; ?> try this one.

Comment: if @SHPatel solution not work then try to replace : href="<?php echo echo Mage::getBaseUrl().'trade/buyingList';
?>"

Comment: Ahh my Bad. Forgot `echo` La...... Silly one

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you forgot "echo"

must be : `<?php echo $this->getBaseUrl().'trade/buyingList'; ?>`

OR

```
<?php echo $this->getUrl('trade/buyingList'); ?>
```

Answer (score 2):

Use `<?php echo $this->getBaseUrl()` or Better Use `echo $this->getUrl('trade/buyingList');`